# Sort by date with Excel file and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sort my Excel file by the date column. When the code runs it turns the cells from a text string to a time date and it sorts, but only within the same month. That is, when I have dates from October and September it completes by the month.

I have been all over Google and YouTube.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

x = datetime.datetime.now()

excel_workbook = 'data.xlsx'
sheet1 = pd.read_excel(excel_workbook, sheet_name='RAW DATA')

sheet1['Call_DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(sheet1['Call_DateTime'])

sheet1.sort_values(sheet1['Call_DateTime'], axis=1, ascending=True, inplace=True)

sheet1['SegmentDuration'] = pd.to_timedelta(sheet1['SegmentDuration'], unit='s')

sheet1['SegmentDuration'] = timedelta(hours=0.222)

sheet1.style.apply('h:mm:ss', column=['SegmentDuration'])

sheet1.to_excel("S4x Output"+x.strftime("%m-%d")+".xlsx", index = False)

print("All Set!!")
```

I would like it to sort oldest to newest.

Comment: Use ` sort_values()` ?

Comment: I have 'sort_values()' and that is what is not working

Comment: @vb_rises I am getting the below error when I change the axis to 1 from 0:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "excel.py", line 13, in <module>
    sheet1.sort_values(['Call_DateTime'], axis=1, ascending=True, inplace=True)
  File "C:\Win Python\python-3.7.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4993, in sort_values
    k = self._get_label_or_level_values(by, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Win Python\python-3.7.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1774, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'Call_DateTime'

Comment: @stilwellj I guess your code is correct. Since you need the oldest value first, you should use `ascending=True` and then check your logic.

Comment: @vb_rises I updated and still getting the error. I tried a print of prior to that line and I am getting dtype: object. I am not sure if that means that it is not converting from a string to a date time format.

Comment: @stilwellj try `sheet1['Call_DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(sheet1['Call_DateTime'])` and then sort.

Comment: Instead of in comments, you ought to put the new information, e.g. the stack trace, into the question (by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58252432/edit)). [This is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115). It is a [think tank](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681).

Comment: @vb_rises I made an edit to my code above and I am still getting an error for key error

Answer (score 0):

Update code and this works.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

x = datetime.datetime.now()

excel_workbook = 'data.xlsx'
sheet1 = pd.read_excel(excel_workbook, sheet_name='RAW DATA')

sheet1['Call_DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(sheet1['Call_DateTime'])

sheet1.sort_values(['Call_DateTime'], axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=True)

sheet1['SegmentDuration'] = pd.to_timedelta(sheet1['SegmentDuration'], unit='s')

sheet1['SegmentDuration'] = timedelta(hours=0.222)

sheet1.style.apply('h:mm:ss', column=['SegmentDuration'])

sheet1.to_excel("S4x Output"+x.strftime("%m-%d")+".xlsx", index = False)

print("All Set!!")
```